# Hierarchical Nester Repeater Repeats the Parent Item

Tags: asp.net, database, ms-access, datatable, repeater

I am trying to generate a Tiered list using nested repeaters from an Access data source.
Each item has a unique ID, but is categorized according to Area.

I would like the list to look something like:

- **Area1**

  - item1
  - item2
- **Area2**

  - item3
  - item4
- **etc**...

Try as I might, the Area group element keeps repeating and I get something like:

- **Area1**

  - item1
- **Area1**

  - item2
- **Area2**

  - item3
- **Area2**

  - item4
- **etc**...

My markup is posted below.

```
      <asp:Repeater ID="CategoryRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="CategoryRepeater_bound" EnableViewState="false">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <ul>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </ul>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li>
                    <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Area"]%>
                </li>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="childRepeater" runat="server">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <ul>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            </ul>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li>
                                <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["ItemID"]%>
                            </li>                     
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>




protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Source.mdb";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cn))
  {

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select ItemID, Area FROM [Location]", conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);


    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Table1");
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Area, ItemID, Drawing FROM [Location]";
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(ds, "Table2");
    ds.Relations.Add(new DataRelation("drTable", ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns["ItemID"], ds.Tables["Table2"].Columns["ItemID"]));
    CategoryRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"];
    CategoryRepeater.DataBind();
  }
}



protected void CategoryRepeater_bound(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

        Repeater rep = (Repeater)item.FindControl("childRepeater");
        rep.DataSource = drv.CreateChildView("drTable");
        rep.DataBind(); 

     }

}
```

Comment: What is the actual question???

Comment: Why does the parent item keep repeating instead of grouping the child items by parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place child repeater inside `<li></li>` tag, at the moment it is outside of it causing major html layout issues. Also your whole logic is incorrect. In your first query you are selecting areas like this `Select ItemID, Area FROM [Location]`, this will return data like this:

```
Area 1  Item 1
Area 1  Item 2
Area 2  Item 3
Area 2  Item 4
```

and so on, so repeater will group accordingly. So when you bind your parent to these results you will get Area1, Area1, Area 2, Area 2... I would avoiid using data tables and probably use something like Linq to SQL or Entity Framework. But in your case the fastest fix would be as follows:

Add label

```
<li>                           
    <asp:Label ID="lblArea" runat="server" Text='<%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Area"]%>' />                       
</li>
```

In code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    {        
    string cn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Source.mdb";        
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cn))      
    {            
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select Area FROM [Location]", conn);        
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);                
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();        
        da.Fill(ds, "Table1");               
        CategoryRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"];                    
        categoryRepeater.DataBind();      
    }    
}

protected void CategoryRepeater_bound(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{             
    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;             
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)             
    {                             
        Repeater rep = (Repeater)item.FindControl("childRepeater");  
        Label lblArea = (Label)item.FindControl("lblArea");  

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select ItemID, Drawind FROM [Location] WHERE Area = '" + lblArea.Text+ "'", conn);        
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);                
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();        
        da.Fill(ds, "Table1");               
        rep.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table1"];                    
        rep.DataBind();  
    }                  
}
```

Comment: That would cause one sql query to run for each area. If instead he fixes the DataRelation, only two queries will be needed.

Comment: Your method is different from all the examples I have seen that use data relations, but it works! Thanks. I did have to use the DISTINCT keyword to prevent the parent from repeating.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're setting up the DataRelation incorrectly. Based on your code you have Area as the parent and ItemId as the child. But when you create the DataRelation you set the columns in both tables to ItemId. This will cause the child table to be one-to-one with the parent table.

You should set the DataRelation on column Area instead. That should fix the issue I believe.

But that will not work if the parent table contains multiple rows with the same Area, so you might have to change the sql used to fill the parent table (Table1). It's not immediately clear if that will be necessary but I think it will. Maybe like this:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select DISTINCT Area FROM [Location]", conn);
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Also see answer by fenix2222 about malformed html.

Comment: I did end up needing the distinct keyword. Thanks!